# Chrome refusing to reconnect to open website after changing network connection type

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet, google-chrome, websites

Using [Google Chrome 40](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.nl/2015/02/stable-channel-update.html) on [Xubuntu 14.10](http://xubuntu.org/news/14-10-release/), I sometimes switch my network connection from wireless to ethernet (or vice versa) while I have some tabs with websites open. After this, I cannot seem to reload the pages that were open during the connection type switch. I can however load websites that I haven't visited to during the current browser session.

I tried looking at the [network performance](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) in Chrome's [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), but it show's me zero info. No response headers, no status code, just '*pending*'. When I open another browser or manually Curl the URL at this point, it responds without any problem. Only Chrome keeps hanging.

Is there any way to avoid or debug this? My guess is that Chrome somehow decides to cache which network connection I use for which website, regardless of the OS. This only happens to me on (X)Ubuntu installs, though. Does anyone have any experience with this?